# Why can't this function see the variables of a file included in an included file?

Tags: php, variables, scope, undefined, require

first post here!
Okay so I have a function containing this code:

```
require_once('../strap.php');

$admin = new Member;
$admin->setName($_POST['username']);
$admin->setPassword($hash);
$admin->setEmail($_POST['email']);
$admin->updateDatabase();
```

the required file looks like this:

```
//define constants
define('ROOTPATH', __DIR__ . '/');
define('CLASSES', __DIR__ . '/classes/');

//Lazy load any required php classes
function __autoload($class_name) {
    $file = CLASSES . $class_name . '.php';
    if( file_exists($file) ) {
        require_once $file;
    } else {
        echo "Can't find ". $file;;
    }
}

//does config exist?
if (!file_exists('config.php')) {
    //redirect to install routine if config does not exist
    header(ROOTPATH . 'admin/install.php') ;
}

require('config.php');

//connect to the database
try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:database='.$conf['database'].';host='.$conf['host'].';port='.$conf['port'].';', 
    $conf['username'], $conf['password']);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die('ERROR: Could not connect: ' . print_r($e->getMessage()));
}
```

and the required file in that (config.php) looks like this:

```
$conf['username'] = 'root';
$conf['password'] = '';
$conf['host'] = 'localhost';
$conf['database'] = 'dddatabase';
$conf['port'] = '3306';
$conf['prefix'] = 'cms_';
```

My problem is that I get this error: Notice: Undefined variable: conf in D:\wamp\www\testing\scripts\CMS\classes\Member.php on line 152

and also

Notice: Undefined variable: pdo in D:\wamp\www\testing\scripts\CMS\classes\Member.php on line 153

When it initialises a new Member object and then calls the updateDatabase() method, which uses the $conf[] array and the $pdo object.

however if I include strap.php again, I get the error: Cannot redeclare __autoload() (previously declared in D:\wamp\www\testing\scripts\CMS\strap.php:16) in D:\wamp\www\testing\scripts\CMS\strap.php on line 23

Does anyone have any idea what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Member class, where you try to access the $pdo, and $conf variables, you need to declare them as global. So inside the Member class, in the function you are trying to use these variables, add the following to the beginning of the function (or at least before you are referencing them):

```
global $conf, $pdo;
```

Comment: Thanks, worked a charm, however I don't really understand it. How does declaring these variables as global, after they have been made, in a function that cannot normally access them, fix this?

Comment: Actually it didn't work, sure the errors are gone, but apparently the variables are empty, they shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1):

I will need to look at your class Member.

But this type of error is thrown when you are trying to use an undefined object variable.

You either need to use a setter to pass $conf to the Member class like this:

require 'config.php';

`$member = new Member();`
`$member->setConfig($conf);`

Internally, your setter and class can look like this:

...

```
/** var array $config **/
private $config = array();


public function  setConfig(array $conf)
{
    $this->config = $conf;
}


public function getPort()
{
    return $this->config['port];
}
```

...

Now, I personally prefer only using classes and avoiding arrays().
If someone else ended using your classes, there would have to understand the array structure rather than the class definition.

A quick re-implementation of what you are trying to achieve, would be something like below:

...

```
php INI File:

[database]
username =  root
password = 1234
database = localhost
host = localhost
```

```
// Immutable value Object



Class Config
{

    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $host;
    private $database;
    private $port;
    private $prefix;

    public function __construct($username, $password, $host, $database, $port, $prefix = 'db_')
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->host     = $host;
        $this->database = $database;
        $this->port     = $port;
        $this->prefix   = $prefix;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getDatabase()
    {
        return $this->database;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getHost()
    {
        return $this->host;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPort()
    {
        return $this->port;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPrefix()
    {
        return $this->prefix;
    }
}


// Entity



class Member
{
    private $name;
    private $password;
    private $email;
    private $config;


    public function setPost($post)
    {
        $this->name     = isset($post->name) ? $post->name : 'admin';
        $this->email    = isset($post->email) ? $post->email : 'admin@localhost';
        $this->password = isset($post->password) ? $post->password : '1234';
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $config
     */
    public function setConfig($config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return $this->config;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $email
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $name
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $password
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

}

class Connection
{
    /**
     * @var  Config $config
     */
    private $config;
    private $connection;

    public function __construct(Config $config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function connect()
    {
        if (!$this->connection instanceof \PDO) {
            $this->connection = new \PDO(
                'mysql:database=' . $this->config->getDatabase() .
                ';host=' . $this->config->getHost() .
                ';port=' . $this->config->getPort() . ';',
                $this->config->getUsername(),
                $this->config->getPassword()
            );
        } else {
            $this->connection;
        }
    }
}
```

...

Then we should now have:

define('ROOTPATH', **DIR** . '/');
    define('CLASSES', **DIR** . '/classes/');

```
//Lazy load any required php classes
function __autoload($class_name) {
    $file = CLASSES . $class_name . '.php';
    if( file_exists($file) ) {
        require_once $file;
    } else {
        echo "Can't find ". $file;;
    }
}

//does config exist?
if (!file_exists('config.ini')) {
    //redirect to install routine if config does not exist
    header(ROOTPATH . 'admin/install.php') ;
}

if(false == $config = parse_ini_file('config.ini')) {
    //Do something else
}


$post = (object)$_POST;
$configClass = new Config(
    $config['username'], 
    $config['password'],   
    $config['host'], 
    $config['database'], 
    $config['port']
);

$connection = new Connection($configClass);

try {
    $connection->connect();
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}

$member = new Member();

//Either

$member->setPost($post);

//OR

$member->setName($post->name);
$member->setEmail($post->email);
$member->setPassword($post->password);


//I do not understand, what you are try to do below but its from your question

$member->updateDatabse();
```

...

I'm not sure of what you are trying to achieve with your member class, is it active record?

DO NOT USE GLOBALS, its trap.